# How to create random number in ifelse function?

Tags: r, if-statement, random

I would like to implement random numbers for the time values equal to 0 (time == 0) and keep other time values as given.

```
set.seed(123)
 df$time.new <- ifelse(df$time == 0, sample(0.2:0.8, replace=F), df$time)
```

Using the formula only 0.2 is created.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is in the sequence `0.2:0.8` you could try `seq(0.2, 0.8, by =0.0001)` or something similar.

Comment: It was my joy and pleasure to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

I will fill the blanks in the comment that answered the question.  This is your code:

```
set.seed(123)
 df$time.new <- ifelse(df$time == 0, sample(0.2:0.8, replace=F), df$time)
```

The key to understand why you are getting always `0.2` is to run:

```
0.2:0.8
```

This just yields: `[1] 0.2` and that's the reason you are always getting `0.2`  The `seq()` command lets you make sequences that have more elements by specifying shorter increments:

```
> seq(0.2, 0.8, by = 0.1)
[1] 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
```

If I remember correctly the default increment for `a:b` is one unit.  Let's check a toy example:

```
> a <- 1; b <- 7
> a:b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If we do this with `a <- 0.2` and `b <- 0.8` the resulting vector would consist of just the value `0.2` hence, your code just detects such value.